# Como puedo cambiar el valor de un DropDowntextField si estoy usando un SingleValueDropdownController?

Tags: flutter

Estoy usando DropDownTextField y no puedo cambiar el valor, tampoco puedo usar initialValue ya que estoy usando un SingleValueDropDownController.

Esta es una imagen del codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]